# How to get zoom level of map?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, maps

I have multiple Annotations in my map I need to see annotation dependent on map zoom level. like if zoom level is max then show all annotations and if zoom level is min show half annotations. but I am unable to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the map zoom level using the following line:

```
mkMkMapview.camera.altitude *= 1.4
```

You can put your priority depending on Annotations.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. What i need is when i zoom out it should show only one annotation and when i start zoom in the no of annotations should increase.

Comment: Thanks for your important time @Sohil